# Can I use different receive/send ports on UDP server for client that are behind the NAT?

Tags: udp, nat

I write UDP server which serves clients that are behind NAT. Clients send request to public IP and some predefined port. Server receives message, creates (gets from pool) thread and 
passes the message to the thread (handler).

The question: may I use new socket (different port) for sending response or should I use the same port (socket) that received the request?

Answer (score 3):

You need to send the request from the same IP,port on the server as it was received on and to the same public visible IP,port on the client where you got the data from. Otherwise the NAT will not be able to translate the IP and port in the packet back to the original client behind the NAT.

You can achieve this requirement by using a single server socket which is bound to the servers IP and port and not connected to a specific client. Then use `recvfrom` to receive data and `sendto` to send, using the address returned by `recvfrom` as the target in `sendto`.

Comment: Yep, I understand. But in this case  all communication on server side should be performed via single socket (port). Is it correct?

Comment: @bw_dev: It is in theory possible to have multiple sockets bound to the same server side IP and port but connected to different clients. These would work also but the design with a single socket is probably more common.